# Converting a column in Spotfire to Power BI

Tags: powerbi

hi I am trying to redo an analytic which is already there in Spotfire to Power Bi. There is calculated column  **Max([ Date]) over ([ContentId])** . 
Can anyone help me with converting this calculated column in Power Bi

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something similar to the following calculation:

```
Calc_Column = CALCULATE(MAX(Table[Date]),ALLEXCEPT(Table,Table[ContentID]))
```

Replace "Table" with the name of your table and you should be good to go. Hope this helps.